# How to remove all occurrences of '{'?

Tags: java, string

How should i remove all occurrence of this character `{` from a String?
I know that i should use `replaceAll` method but this does not work?

```
String str = "this is {something";
str = str.replaceAll("{", "");
```

Comment: What does _this does not work_ mean? Have you read the javadoc of the methods you are using? Have you investigated any error messages?

Comment: well actually it throws Illegal repetition exception

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`replaceAll` uses a regular expression as its argument. `{` is used in regular expressions to denote the occurrences of a match, therefore it needs to be escaped

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\{", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [`replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29), not [`replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) as you are not using a Regex but a simple pair of Strings. Despite their names, they both replace all occurrences of the specified Strings.